# Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel.InMemoryTransmitter.Runner()

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, azure-application-insights, memory-dump

Thread xx - System ID xxxxx This thread is waiting in a WaitOne
Entry point   clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc

Full Call Stack

```
ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+c 
KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+f0 
clr!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx_SO_TOLERANT+3c 
clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+237 
clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+64 
clr!WaitHandleNative::CorWaitOneNative+163 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, Int64, Boolean, Boolean)+21 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, Int64, Boolean, Boolean)+21 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(System.TimeSpan, Boolean)+60 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(System.TimeSpan, Boolean)+60 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(System.TimeSpan)+17 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(System.TimeSpan)+17 
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel.InMemoryTransmitter.Runner()+7b 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()+28 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()+30
```

I am getting following memory leak in the azure memory dump analysis. Can you tell me what I am missing. I'm using .Net 4.6.1 framework & application-insight 2.11.0.0

Comment: How did you realize that this is a memory leak?..

Comment: @ArtemRazin we ran Memory dump against the Azure app service. On the analyst it mentioned the thread is waiting in a WaitMultiple

Answer (score 1):

This is the app insights channel waiting on there being telemetry to send.  the channel waits for a number of items or a certain amount of time has elapsed before sending telemetry in batches. It's existance by itself is not really a "leak", but it could depending on the definition of "leak" and how long the channel buffers items before sending them.

If you think this is a true leak, the best pace to report it is in the .net sdk's github:

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I already raised an issue, there is no response from their end. fyr, https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1332